# getting a 'name' based URL in RESTful routes instead of an id based url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

If I implement RESTful routing for a controller 'galleries' like as follows:

```
map.resources :galleries
```

By default the show url for this controller would be:

```
/galleries/:id
```

which would respond to any requests to /galleries/1 etc.

What if I had a gallery record in the database with a 'name' attribute with value 'portraits'.
Could I do the same as follows:

```
/galleries/portraits
```

instead of doing

```
/galleries/1 ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Gallery` model, add a `#to_param` method that returns what you want in the URL (in this case, `name`). In your controller, you still access the value through `params[:id]` and you'll probably have to use `Gallery#find_by_name` instead of `Gallery#find`.

As long as you use the provided helpers (`gallery_path`, etc.), your URLs should be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to think of what happens if the gallery name is something not very URL-friendly like 'Autumn/Fall2009#1' where you have a forward slash (will change the routing) and a dash (will not be submitted to the server if left unencoded). So, you will need urlencoding when generating such URLs.

Comment: ah I see your point and now I understand why that option wasnt built-in, but im just making a simple photoblog for myself and ill be responsible for adding galleries myself, so that wasnt a concern.