# Confused about routes setup -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I think I'm running across a conflict due to names:

Two models: `store` `coupon`

Url needed that will display coupons: `http://localhost/coupons/:store_name` ('coupons' is written in the url, not replaced with anything)

Controller name: `coupons_controller`

Here is what I have in my routes right now:

`match '/coupons/:store_name' => 'coupons#index', :as => :stores`

When I try to do `redirect stores_path(store)` in another controller, I get this error:

`No route matches {:controller=>"coupons"}`

Any clues? I'm new to rails so I bet it's a silly mistake.

**UPDATE**

Is there a central place to tell the dynamic _path() functions to use a specific url structure? i.e. Instead of having to do the following everywhere:

`redirect_to stores_path(:store_name => store.store_name)`

Instead using just:

`redirect_to stores_path(store)`

Comment: Just making that you've restarted your rails server after editing the routes file?

Comment: :) I didn't know it needed a restart -- but I've got another problem now... the urls generated are like `/coupons/1234` which is the store's id. How can I automatically have it put in the name when i call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can, redefine `to_param` in your model:

```
class Store < ...
  def to_param
    store_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect_to stores_path(:store_name => store)
```

should work if it doesn't (cannot confirm right now), you should be able to do the (little hacky)

```
redirect_to stores_path+"?store_name=yourstorename"
```

Doing it the restful way, you should probably have something like this (in your routes):

```
resources :stores do
  resources :coupons # this will give you e.g. /stores/:store_id/coupons for the coupons#index action
end
```

If you want to use the store name instead of the ID, just search SO for using "slug" or have a look here: [getting a 'name' based URL in RESTful routes instead of an id based url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989504/getting-a-name-based-url-in-restful-routes-instead-of-an-id-based-url) or [ID + Slug name in URL in Rails (like in StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632732/id-slug-name-in-url-in-rails-like-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: That works but is there a way I can set this as a standard (so can just pass in the object and tell it somewhere to use the store_name instead of the store_id)?